# Start a child process in COBOL

Tags: cobol, child-process, gnucobol

How to start a child process in GnuCOBOL?

In Node.js, we can use either `spawn` or `exec` to start child processes:

```
var proc = require("child_process").spawn("ls", ["-l"]);
proc.stdout.on("data", function (chunk) {
  console.log(chunk);
});

// or

var proc = require("child_process").exec("ls -l"], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
   ...
});
```

Both of the examples above run `ls -l` (list the files and directories). How can the same thing be achieved in COBOL?

Comment: What Cobol ???; in Mainframe CICS/Cobol you would use the CICS START command

Comment: @BruceMartin I'm using `GNUCobol`. Could you add an example?

Comment: Not something I can answer. I have copied the question to GNU Cobol forum (https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/thread/8ae787f2/) so they are aware of it; I would imagine Bill/Brian will answer it shortly. Also added GNU-Cobol tag

Comment: @BruceMartin Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a common COBOL extension which is supported since years in GnuCOBOL (formerly OpenCOBOL), too:

```
CALL 'SYSTEM' USING whatever END-CALL
```

This works with 'cobcrun', too and can be useful if you need a COBOL process with a separate environment (`EXTERNAL` items, `ACCEPT x FROM y` / `SET ENVIRONMENT y TO x`) or runtime configuration (for example via `cobcrun -c different.cfg OTHERMAIN`).

Your original sample may look like (without the option to use pipes which would be a different question):

```
CALL 'SYSTEM' USING 'ls -l >dirlist'
  ON EXCEPTION
    CALL 'SYSTEM' USING 'dir >dirlist'
    END-CALL
END-CALL
```

Afterwards you can read the dirlist as a normal line sequential file.

Simon

BTW: Given your sample you *may* look for `CALL 'C$LISTDIR'`.

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Brian pointed out http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fork#COBOL for details on forking in cobol